# Converting a Openshift Route to Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

I have a Openshift Route of type :

```
- apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
  kind: Route
  metadata:
    name: <Route name>
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: <name>
  spec:
    host: <hostname>
    port:
      targetPort: http
    tls:
      termination: passthrough
    to:
      kind: Service
      name: <serviceName>
```

I want to convert it into a Ingress Object as there are no routes in bare k8s. I couldn't find any reference to tls termination as passthrough in Ingress documentation. Can someone please help me converting this to an Ingress object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLS passthrough is not officially part of the Ingress spec. Some specific ingress controllers support it, usually via non-standard TCP proxy modes. But what you probably want is a LoadBalancer-type service.

Comment: The LoadBalancer-type Service would essentially allow me to achieve the same functionality? 
So essentially I will have to define the service with type as loadbalancer and go on defining an Ingress which would expose that service without any mention of TLS termination.

Comment: Yes, a Service with type LoadBalancer is a pure TCP tunnel, it doesn't touch the actual data.